# video.js for WordPress : JavaScript error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, wordpress, video.js

I'm using [Video.js - HTML5 Video Player for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/videojs-html5-video-player-for-wordpress/) with WordPress 3.5 . My MP4 video is playing normally in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not Internet Explorer 8. It shows a JavaScript error:

```
Invalid Argument
video.js     Line: 21
Code: 0   Char: 29906
URI: http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js
```

As I saw from this [post](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/problems/384-javascript-error-in-ie8) in video.js support forum, many users report the same error but seems no solution is provided. Is there anybody who can provide some lights to me?

**UPDATE :** Here is the shortcode I use:

> [video mp4="http://video/path/here.mp4" width="95%"]

Nothing else in the post content. WordPress version: 3.5

Currently activated plugins installed:

- Fancybox for WordPress v3.0.2
- Bulk Watermark v1.5.1
- AP Extended Mime Types v1.1 ( some people in the Internet suggests installing this will fix the issue , but it doesn't fix at all )
- Video.js - HTML5 Video Player for WordPress v3.2.2

Comment: Thanks for asking question I also suffer same problem.

Comment: Can you show us the related code, or perhaps link to a blog entry that raises this error?

Comment: @JonathanSampson added more information. thanks for the reminder. The site content is still under NDA, thus can't post it out yet.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Can you please link to a page that contains this error?

Comment: I will try to a dummy WordPress site, but as said before, it's in Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA), contents will be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The issue is the following code:**

```
el.style.width=initWidth+"px"
```

This code can be found in the video.js file. You'll need to host the file locally to make the edit below.

You're probably using 100% width on your video. Therefore videojs is attempting to set the width of the parent div to "100%px". This of course won't work.

**Change the line above to:**

```
el.style.width=initWidth.indexOf('%') !== -1 ? initWidth : initWidth+"px";
```